# Trying to upload a url that includes user credentials gets an error of "nonnumeric port"

Tags: amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to S3 using url that requires user authentication.
The url looks like-"http://user:pass@domain.com/url".

But I get this error-
 "errorType": "InvalidURL", "errorMessage": "nonnumeric port: 'user:pass'"

Any idea how I can solve it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. S3 doesn't support basic auth. You must be uploading the file to somewhere other than S3.

Comment: I did not know that.. are you sure? I means that the url to the file contains user name and password, in the browser it works as expected.

Comment: Works as expected to what endpoint? Where did you get the URL?

Comment: In the browser? I can see the file.. I got the url from an xml.

Comment: You have a URL which contains basic auth in the form `https://user:password@example.com/cat.png`. You can paste this into a browser and retrieve `cat.png` from the example.com site (which requires basic auth). How is this relevant to uploading a file to S3?

Comment: I meant that when I try to upload the file *using that url* I get this error.. I am doing this in java.

Comment: You aren't "uploading the file with that URL". You're downloading the file from that URL and then, presumably, you want to upload the resulting file to S3. The first part of this, the download, has nothing to do with S3. So, get the file, however you want to, then upload it to S3 using the AWS Java SDK. There are plenty of examples of how to both of these things.

Comment: ok, thanks! I will try to see how to do it.